# Indexing vectors in r language

Tags: r, vector, indexing

i need to index a vector in a specific way

For example i have the following vector:

`x = c(1,1,2,3,1,1,2,3)`

the output of the function must return a vector like this

`[1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6]`

If a number repeats in the vector `x` then the output vector must handle the index as the same number

The function must only account for consecutive repeated numbers

Here's what i have tried to do

```
svector <- function(x){

y = c()

for (i in 1:NROW(x)){

if((x[-length(x)] == x[-1])){

y[i] = y[i+1] 

}else{

next

}
 } 
  }
```

In my program i try to read the first and second entry in the vector,compare if there the same, then in an empty vector `y` insert the entries

Comment: If `x = c(1,1,2,3,1,1,2,3)`, what should the output be?

Comment: @MelissaKey    Write it up as an answer?

Comment: @CPak `[1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6]` it only accounts repeated consecutive numbers

Comment: @blazedosan002 ok - the highest voted comment will give the wrong answer - can you update your post to add the 2nd scenario?

Comment: @CPak  i have updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all entries with the same value need to have the same index, we would use

```
as.numeric(factor(x, levels = unique(x)))
```

This assumes that non-consecutive repeats of the variety mentioned by @CPak are ignored.  When the index should be different, the following works:

```
library(dplyr) # for lag function
cumsum(x != lag(x, default = 0))
```

or

```
cumsum(x != c(0, x[-length(x)]))
```

which avoids the `lag` function

Answer (score 0):

The `rleid` function in the `data.table` package is for exactly this purpose. Should be many times faster.

```
x <- sample(1:5e4, 1e6, T)

all.equal(rleid(x), cumsum(x != lag(x, default = 0)))
# TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(custom = cumsum(x != lag(x, default = 0)), 
               rleid = rleid(x), unit = 'relative')

# Unit: relative
#    expr      min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  custom 5.481059 6.52852 4.660912 6.816693 5.586913 1.550265   100
#   rleid 1.000000 1.00000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
```